# installing from bower repository from private gitlab repository

Tags: git, bower, gitlab, bower-install

I try to install a bower repo i registered to my local private bower instance.
The git host is a private gitlab instance.

bower install bower-test is given me the error

```
bower bower-test#*          not-cached git://github.com/EvandroLG/bower-test.git#*
bower bower-test#*             resolve git://github.com/EvandroLG/bower-test.git#*
bower bower-test#*             ECMDERR Failed to execute "git ls-remote --tags --heads     git://github.com/EvandroLG/bower-test.git", exit code of #128

Additional error details:
     fatal: remote error: 
     Repository not found.
```

I know that private-bower is running correctly because i registered a github.com repository which i can install.

my .bowerrc

```
{
  "registry" : {
    "register" : "http://localhost:5678"
  },
"search": [
      "http://localhost:5678"
   ]
}
```

i can run

```
bower install http://myprivategitlabip/bower/bower-test.git
```

with success (with providing credentials).

But i like to run

```
bower install bower-test
```

any suggestions?

Comment: if you use bower search, which results do you get?

Answer (score 0):

Probably a bit late to answer but I just ran into this myself and fixed it by the following steps:

- Generate a key (i.e.):

  ssh-keygen -o -f repo-rsa-key
- Add public key to Gitlib repository
- Add private key to Gitlab runner

Should build fine after that.